# How to enforce static imports for some methods using checkstyle?

Tags: java, static-analysis, checkstyle

How to enforce static imports for some methods using checkstyle?

For example

I want the following method to be used only from static import:

```
import static java.util.Objects.isNull;
import static java.util.Objects.nonNull;
```

So code like this shouldn't be allowed:

```
if (Objects.nonNull(varName)) {
```

Any ideas how to achieve that with (preferably) standard or non standard tools?

Comment: How will you handle using methods of the same name from different classes?

Comment: You can implement custom rules in CheckStyle, FindBugs or PMD.  But, seriously, most Java programmers (and most Style guidelines) would consider using static imports like that to be bad style.

Comment: @Bohemian it will not be an issue. Since we need to enforce 3-4 methods with almost 0% chance of collision with others libs.

Comment: @StephenC Wanted to avoid writing custom solution for that. Regarding style: agree - but now it's quite messy because half of devs use one style and another half use another.

Comment: @StephenC I personally prefer static imports because it makes code more readable (especially Collectors etc), but would never consider *enforcing* it.

Comment: @Bohemian - Hmmm ... style conventions are evolving.

Comment: @nikopol86 - Well, I doubt that you will find a standard rule to do this.  Not least because you only want to enforce this for two specified methods.  That is a very  "special case" or "local" rule.

Comment: @StephenC Seriously... Considering static imports a bad style is... No more than an unfounded religion. Sure there are cases it is a bad style. As is the one provided in original question.

Comment: You misquoted me.  I said "... would consider using static imports **like that** to be bad style". Obviously "like that" refers to the OP's example.

Comment: @StephenC unfortunately all my comment didn't fit into the the comment length limit, so I think it deserves an answer :) Because just mentioning 'like that' is not really explaining what exactly is wrong with those.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  Comments are no intended to be answers ... and I don't intend to write an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could forbid the String that imports Objects:

```
<module name="RegexpSinglelineJava">
    <!-- Please statically import methods -->
    <property name="format" value="import java.util.Objects;"/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pease! Never use static import for `Objects.isNull` / `Objects.nonNull`... Not because static imports are bad. But the use of `isNull()` / `nonNull()` instead of `== null` / `!= null` is bad. We used those operators in Java for 20 years before `Objects.isNull` / `Objects.nonNull` methods appeared (together with introduction of lambdas in Java 8) and there is no reason to change that practice. Using `isNull()` / `notNull()` just introduces inconsistent style and confuse local static analysis tools. They are no more clear than a language feature existed since day one.

Read the JavaDoc - those methods have quite specific purpose and it is not to replace / compete with (in)equality operators:

**API Note:**
This method exists to be used as a Predicate, `filter(Objects::isNull)`

Regarding the original question - there is currently no way to force static imports for particular methods in Checkstyle (and any other static analysis tool for Java I know of). Only forbidding is possible. I really wish it would be possible to do both as I myself find static imports quite useful and providing better clarity to the code in many circumstances (as well as a source of abuse such as in afore mentioned example and trying to import too ambiguous names such as `of` or `ofNullable`).

But currently you are limited to making your own Checkstyle plugin for that.